# Call of undefined function xmlwriter_open_memory(), no OOP

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

I am writing a school project in PHP but I am not using classes. I need to write the output to XML with wmlwriter_open_memory() and tried things like this:

```
$xml = xmlwriter_open_memory();

$xml = XMLWriter::xmlwriter_open_memory();

$xml = new XMLWriter();
...
```

But I get the call to undefined function error, but the curious thing is, I don't get the error when I remotely run in on the school server.

I am using PHP 7.2.15 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: php compile whith `--disable-xmlwriter`

Comment: You PHP does not include the XMLWriter extension. Depending on the OS you might need to install an additional package or just activate the extension in the `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @ThW has stated, I didn't have the extension installed, but my IDE recognized that the function exists, so that confused me the most.

I've solved it by installing the php extension like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

and made sure that it is installed with this

```
php -i | grep "xml"
```

I found these commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044656/how-can-i-install-xmlwriter)